# Producer/Consumer deadlock multithreading Java

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock, producer-consumer

I am trying to solve the Producer/Consumer problem in Java using multi-threading, but I keep getting stuck in a deadlock and I can't figure out why.

**BoundedBuffer.java**

```
public class BoundedBuffer {
    private final int[] buffer;
    private final int N;
    private int in = 0;
    private int out = 0;
    private int itemCount = 0;

    public BoundedBuffer(int size) {
        N = size + 1; 
        buffer = new int[N];
    }

    public void insert(Producer producer, int item) {
        synchronized (producer) {
            while ( (in + 1) % N == out) {
                try {
                    producer.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
        }
        buffer[in] = item;
        in = (in + 1) % N;
        itemCount++;
    }

    public int remove(Consumer consumer) {
        synchronized (consumer) {
            while (in == out) {
                try {
                    consumer.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            }

            int item = buffer[out];
            buffer[out] = null;
            out = (out + 1) % N;
            itemCount--;

            return item;
        }
    }
}
```

**Producer.java**

```
public class Producer extends Thread {
    private int total = 0;
    private BoundedBuffer buffer;
    private int uniqueItem = 0;

    public Producer(int total, BoundedBuffer b) {
        this.total = total;
        this.buffer = b;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < quota; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random() * 100));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
            buffer.insert(this, uniqueItem++);
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

**Consumer.java**

```
public class Consumer extends Thread {
    private int total = 0;
    private BoundedBuffer buffer;

    public Consumer(int total, BoundedBuffer b) {
        this.total = total;
        this.buffer = b;
    }

    public void run() {
        for (int i = 0; i < total; i++) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep((int)(Math.random() * 100));
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}         
            buffer.remove(this);
            this.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

This code will run for a while and when I have debugging set ("This producer is trying to insert this item...") I see a nice pattern coming along, but every now and then I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-2" java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException
    at java.lang.Object.notifyAll(Native Method)
    at Consumer.run(Consumer.java:19)
```

And then I have a deadlock occur some time after that.

I think my issue is due to the key I am synchronizing on, the `producer` and `consumer` instances. I'm not sure what else I could synchronize the method on, and that is what is stumping me most. I believe I could have a key for each consumer/producer to share, but I'm not sure how that would work.

Comment: Why do you think there is a deadlock?

Comment: @jameslarge https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer%E2%80%93consumer_problem
Not a constructive comment btw.

Comment: @HongDuan I believe the deadlock was caused because I was synchronizing on the Producer and Consumer instances, so no one else would be able to get a lock if I wait()ed on an instance.

Comment: @Zach OK, comment retracted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should synchronize on the `BoundedBuffer` itself, and use `wait` inside the synchronized blocks to release the lock and wait until the other thread notifies the sleeping one.

There's a complete example in this tutorial:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/guardmeth.html

Also, please note that you can now use a `BlockingQueue` to implement a Consumer-Producer patter in a much more simple way.

Here you have the documentation for the `BlockingQueue` showing a much more simpler Consumer-Producer implementation:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html

Comment: This worked for multiple Producer's and Consumer's! What I did was `synchronize(this)` and called `this.wait()` inside the block, then outside of that block I called `notifyAll()`. I removed `notifyAll()` from Producer.java and Consumer.java as well. Thank you very much!

Comment: One issue I'm still having is it seems like multiple producers are creating items with the same ID, event after I declare `uniqueItem` static. What can I do? @eugenioy

Comment: You can use an `AtomicInteger` for `uniqueItem` and do `uniqueItem.inrementAndGet()` instead of `uniqueItem++`

Comment: There is an issue still...when I've got an unequal amount of Producers/Consumers I get a deadlock again. Any advice?

Comment: I believe you should post a new question with your new code and adding a way to reproduce the issue.